# Regular map $f:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^n$ is constant

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to know if the following argument goes through. The base field is $\mathbb{C}$.

Suppose $f:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^1$ is a regular map (it suffices to prove the statement for this case). Then, $f=\frac{P}{Q}$ for homogeneous polynomials of equal degree $P, Q$ such that $Q(x)\neq 0$. But if $Q$ is a polynomial with no roots, it follows from the fundamental theorem of algebra that its degree is zero. Then, $f=cP$ for some constant $c$; and in order for it to remain well-defined on $\mathbb{P}^1$, we must also require $P$ to have degree zero. This proves the claim.

Comment: What's your definition of regular function on $\mathbb{P}^1$? Because it is not the one that appears in Chapter 1 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: I am following Shafarevich's book. For him, a rational function on a projective variety is a fraction of homogeneous polynomials with equal degree, and a regular function is rational at a point $x$ if the denominator doesn't vanish there. If the denominator doesn't vanish at all points of the variety, the function is regular.

Comment: You probably want to say at some point in the proof that you take $P$ and $Q$ to be co-prime. That $Q$ has no roots requires some justification, since for example $(x-1)/(x-1)$ has no poles but $x-1$ has a zero at $x=1$.